# "The file exists" error while deploying wsp file on of the my web application in moss 2007

Tags: 2007

I am getting "the file exist" error while deploying wsp file on my web application in moss 2007.

error is:
servername : "The File exists"

please help me to find the cause and solution for this error.
thank you.

Comment: Please, check your sharepoint logs and provide more detailed error information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error if the WSP you are deploying is attempting to deploy a DLL that is also deployed in another WSP.  If that is the case, make one WSP be responsible for the DLL and remove it from the deployment instructions in the other WSP.

Comment: thanks for reply.actually we are using third party wsp(Bamboo) so we dont have source code to this modification.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 're-deploying' an already deployed solution you should try to use the stsadmin upgradesolution, refer to the following for syntax:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262014(v=office.12).aspx 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262014(office.12).aspx

Beyond this as omlin said above we need more info.